# IBM Watson Discovery service - java API query builder with filter throwing stackoverflow error

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, watson-discovery

The below is the query I need to build using Java API for IBM Watson discovery service.

```
nested(enriched_text.entities)
.filter(enriched_text.entities.type::"Date_of_incident")
.term(enriched_text.entities.text,count:10)
```

I am trying to build the query as below using Java API.

```
queryBuilder.aggregation("nested(enriched_text.entities)");
queryBuilder.filter("enriched_text.entities.type::\"Date_of_incident\"");
queryBuilder.aggregation("term(enriched_text.entities.text,count:10)");
```

but the filter part is throwing StackOverflow error when trying to execute.